# Return custom values from WPF dialog

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

I am using `Window.ShowDialog()` method to fetch some values from the user. However, the dialog will only return a nullable bool.

How can I get my WPF window to return a `Tuple<string,string>` or any other type?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need to return that value from the ShowDialog method, as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx):
*"A Nullable<(Of <(T>)>) value of type Boolean that signifies how a window was closed by the user".*

You can simply store the value you want to return in a property or field and get it:

```
window.ShowDialog();
Tuple<string, string> value = window.InputValue;
```

Answer (score 4):

You could add a new method to your Window, something like this:

```
public Tuple<string, string> ShowTupleDialog()
{
    var retTuple = new  Tuple<string, string>();
    this.ShowDialog();
    // values from dialog to retTuple (maybe use 
    //databinding and return an already defined tuple)
    return retTuple;
}
```